# Pywin32 Adding new page to a word document

Tags: python, ms-word, com, pywin32, win32com

So I have some pictures that I want to insert each in a page. I can insert the first picture into the first page by creating a drawing canvas and inserting into it, but I can't seem to find how to add a new page to insert another picture into it.

```
CanvasWidth= 900
CanvasHeight = 700
mycanvas = WordDoc.app.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCanvas(75, 75, CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight)
pic = mycanvas.CanvasItems.AddPicture(r'C:\temp\c.png')
pic.Height = CanvasHeight
pic.Width = CanvasWidth

WordDoc.app.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Selection.InsertBreak(2)

mycanvas2 = WordDoc.app.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCanvas(75, 75, CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight)
pic2 = mycanvas2.CanvasItems.AddPicture(r'C:\temp\c.png')
pic2.Height = CanvasHeight
pic2.Width = CanvasWidth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word doesn't really have a concept of a page as a structural element under direct user control. It controls pagination, and if you change the font or the margins it will completely repaginate your document without permission.

Insert the two pictures one after the other. If Word decides they will fit on one page it will put them on one page; if not, not.

To force a page break between the two pictures, insert a page or column break, or style the second paragraph as *page break before*.

Comment: I thought about page breaks but can't seem to figure how to insert them

Comment: `Selection.InsertBreak()` should do it.

Comment: Thanks! How would I insert the break at the end of the page?